# How to redirect pure servlet url to the same servlet with default parameters?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, redirect

We have a web application provided by an external supplier. There is a servlet which - if called without parameters - raises an exception. We have access to `web.xml`.

Is it possible to redirect the servlet url `http://<server>:8080/<app>/<servlet>` to the same servlet with default parameters, e.g. to `http://<server>:8080/<app>/<servlet>?p1=0`?

I know that a redirect is possible using Apache and `.htaccess` using the [rewrite engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580831/redirect-url-without-parameter). However, I wonder if there are other means relying on tomcat only.

Comment: If you can change the `web.xml`, you can also write code. You could add a filter in front of that servlet that uses the [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) to add the missing parameters, if needed. Or you could extend the servlet's class (if neither the class nor the relevant methods are final) and implement this functionality. Then use the extended class as `servlet-class` in the `web.xml`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Your comment was edited about one hour early as the answer from worpet below. Because the answer below contains essentially the same suggestions as in your comments, I would like to mark your comment as answer. If you like, just add your comment as answer and I will mark it. Some hints are welcome how to add the default parameters to the request if the filter approach is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the filter solution that you seem to prefer, you first need an implementation of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` that knows about your default values. It could be as:

```
public class SpecializedHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private static final Map<String,String> DEFAULT_VALUES = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        Map<String,String> defaultValues = new HashMap<>();
        defaultValues.put("p1", "0");
        // add other defaults here...
        DEFAULT_VALUES = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(defaultValues);
    }

    public SpecializedHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    public String getParameter(String name) {
        String result = super.getParameter(name);
        if( name == null && DEFAULT_VALUES.containsKey(name) ) {
            result = DEFAULT_VALUES.get(name);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Map<String,String[]> getParameterMap() {
        // needs implementing!
    }

    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
        // needs implementing!
    }

    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        // needs implementing!
    }

    ...
}
```

The implementation of the unimplemented methods above is more complicated, but still doable.

Then the filter code would simply do:

```
void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(new SpecializedHttpServletRequestWrapper(request), response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to force a redirect solely via a configuration file, as is possible with Apache. Using Tomcat only you would have to do this via Java code (write a Filter or Servlet to add the missing parameter values or to redirect to a URL that contains the paramters).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness. Based on the [answer from Nikos Paraskevopoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26998380/2107731) I found a simpler solution:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest && response instanceof HttpServletResponse)
        {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            if ( ! httpRequest.getParameterNames().hasMoreElements())
            {
                String redirectURL = httpRequest.getRequestURL() + "?p1=0";
                httpResponse.setStatus(404); // Not found
                httpResponse.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    ... // implement other interface methods
}
```